# Spark stream with console sink wants HDFS write access

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hdfs

I do have a simple setup of reading from Kafka and writing to local console:

`SparkSession` is created with `.master("local[*]")`
and I start the stream with:

```scala
var df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").options(...).load()
df = df.select("some_column")

df.writeStream.format("console")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

The same Kafka setup works perfectly fine when using with batch/normal `DataFrame`, but for this streaming job I do get the exception:
`Permission denied: user=user, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x`

Why does it want access to HDFS, when I want to get the data locally to the console?
And how can I solve this?

Comment: I assume you're running using spark-submit without any custom options? What Spark version?

Comment: You may need to specify the location of the checkpoint directory. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65574234/read-data-from-kafka-and-print-to-console-with-spark-structured-sreaming-in-pyth).

Comment: @HristoIliev I tried, but every location will get interpreted as HDFS location, where I still don't have write access.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Right assumption. Spark version = "3.2.1" and Scala version = "2.12.10"

Comment: Try adding the `checkpointLocation` option; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44889408/1843329